# How to avoid NPE in array AND keep from referencing the same index?

Tags: arrays, string, reference, indexing, nullpointerexception

In a class I have the field:

```
public static String[] substring;
```

Now I have tried to initialize this variable with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBSTRING; i++){
    substring[i] = new String();
}
```

But what happens is I get an NPE, on the line with substring[i].  I know this is because substring didn't get a value when it was declared, but when I give it value what happens is each of the indices points to the same location.  Kind of like if every book was pointing to another book, and opening one book means all the others open up at the same time.

```
public static String[] substring = new String[MAX_STRING];
```

Any changes I make to any index of this array affects the rest of them.  With this above way I can avoid the NPE, but then the other problem happens!

Still a beginner, can anyone help me?

I am using Java.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Java (because you didn't specify).

The initialization of the vector substring is good. I can't replicate your problem. How do you change the vector elements?

Also, does MAX_STRING and MAX_SUBSTRING have the same value? Why did you declare substring as a static variable?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Christmas keeps me busy.
Thanks for reminding me to point out my language, I will do that in the future (in this case, yes it is Java).

I'm using the substrings within a static class, and I do not instantiate the class.  
The misuse of the constants was my bad, I was typing and forgot 'SUB'.